# Show distinct eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

> Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix (i.e. equal to its conjugate transpose $A^H$) having eigenvectors $x, y$ with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.  Show $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

---

My proof is below. Please verify, critique, or improve.

Proof:

$$\begin{align}
\lambda_1 x^Hy &= (Ax)^Hy  \\
&= x^HAy \quad \text{(since }A=A^H\text{)} \\
&= x^H(\lambda_2y) \\
&= \lambda_2 x^Hy \quad \text{(by linearity)}.
\end{align}$$

Since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2, x^Hy = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

What the proof is missing is to mention the fact that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are real because $A$ is Hermitian. Otherwise you would have to start with $\overline\lambda_1$ and the argument doesn't work.

As a very minor point, if you are into writing the proof carefully, you should have one more step in $(Ax)^Hy=x^HA^Hy=x^HAy$.